# Python 3: Round very large decimal number (of decimal type) from far left

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, rounding

I'm working with atomic clocks, and the frequencies there are like of the order of 10 MHz with over 18 digits precision. So, for some Python application, I need to subtract the mean of a list and call it offset, so that I can use numpy's float64 for this list's element.

My problem is the following: Say I have this number:

```
d = decimal.Decimal('12345678999999.555544333221')
```

I would like to be able to round this number with such a function:

```
large_round(d,5)
```

and get the result:

```
12345000000000.000000000000
```

So I want the rounding to be taken from the far-left, not from the decimal point.

My solution: I can, like, play games and convert this number to a string, and then look for the decimal point, and then count how many digits I have to the left, and then add it to the standard Python `round` function's second parameter.

But I always find functions in Python for everything I imagine. So, is there a Pythonic, friendly way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Divide the number by value `10*n`, round the number and multiply it back by `10*n`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Is there a way to get `n` without having to parse the number as a string? Or perhaps taking some `log`s?

Comment: Well ... `getcontext().prec = 5; d = Decimal('12345678999999.555544333221') + 0`. But, yeah ...

Comment: @dhke lol... this is really evil... Actually I don't dare to do that. It might ruin all other stored numbers!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Well what is the issue with converting it into `str`? PS: I do not know any *efficient* way to do it with converting it to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d2 = decimal.Context(prec=5).create_decimal(d)
```

Create a new context with the desired precision, and use that context to create a new Decimal from `d`.

Comment: Does this modify the main context? or does it create a temporary one?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: This doesn't affect the global context.

Comment: Perfect! I'll try this! Thanks!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Note that the result will be Decimal('1.2346E+13'), with 5 significant digits, so if you wanted all those trailing zeros in your question to be considered significant digits, you might have to adjust that. Also, the default rounding mode is ROUND_HALF_EVEN, a.k.a. rounding to nearest with ties rounding towards even. This doesn't match the output in your question either. I suspect you just made a rounding error in your question, but if you really did want rounding toward zero or toward negative infinity, you can specify that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these details out. That's OK, though. I only want to reduce the number of digits I have to subtract. It's alright :)